Lost connection to device
I try to run flutter app in iOS simulator...
but its show me lost connection to device error every time...
Lost connection to device.
Error: Unable to terminate com.myPackageName.Dev on 6EAC7BBF-3767-44C4-886A-35D72D963210:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally with exit code 3:
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=3):
Simulator device failed to terminate com.myPackageName.Dev.
found nothing to terminate
Underlying error (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=3):
    The request to terminate "com.myPackageName.Dev" failed. found nothing to terminate
    found nothing to terminate
  Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun simctl terminate 6EAC7BBF-3767-44C4-886A-35D72D963210 com.myPackageName.Dev
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.

This error happen only for iOS simulator... work fine on android emulator...
I tried every posible solution ...
flutter clean , flutter doctor , flutter run 

restarting the machine
deleting the drive data
Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 2
Dart 3.3.3
Flutter doctor result :
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.5, on macOS 14.4.1 23E224 darwin-arm64, locale en-PK)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.88.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    ! Error: Browsing on the local area network for Johnny’s iPhone 12 mini. Ensure the device is unlocked and attached with a cable or
      associated with the same local area network as this Mac.
      The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code -27)
    ! Error: Browsing on the local area network for Johnny ipad. Ensure the device is unlocked and attached with a cable or associated with
      the same local area network as this Mac.
      The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code -27)
    ! Error: Browsing on the local area network for iPhone  14 pro. Ensure the device is unlocked and attached with a cable or associated with
      the same local area network as this Mac.
      The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code -27)
[✓] Network resources


To solve this issue:

Close Simulator completely (from the dock, right-click -> "Quit")

Close XCode (if applicable)

Run flutter clean

Re-open Simulator Re-open XCode and let it compile Run the app again


If it still does not work, try resetting the device at "Device" -> "Erase All Content and Settings..." from the Simulator menu.
Happy Coding :)

I tried both solutions ... but still getting the same error ... :(

Stopping the app and running flutter clean worked for me.
